# Ajax call not being received in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I am attempting to make an ajax call from my .html flask to my views.py file using Flask.
The ajax call does not seem to be reaching my .py file for some reason.

Ajax call in html file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<script>
  function getFlashcard(id)
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "{{ url_for('views.get_flashcard') }}",
      data: {"id" : id},
      success: function(){
        alert("success")
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("error")
      }
    });
  }
  
</script>
```

views.py file

```
@views.route('/get_flashcard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def get_flashcard():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("recieved request")
```

Comment: Debug steps to try: View source in the browser, to check the rendered html has the `url` line of the `ajax` call rendered correctly (`url: "/get_flashcard",`).  Check your browsers dev tools to ensure no JS errors are present on the **Console** tab, then use the **Network** tab to see the response code of the request (and that the request did infact fire).  Also view your flask dev sever console for some kind of error (or to see if the request was received).

Comment: Thank you, that helped solve my bug. I was using a slim version of jquery.